# Ways to decrease TVS diode capacitance

Tags: capacitor, ethernet, high-frequency, tvs

I am currently working on high speed ethernet data line, and I wanted to know if there is a way to decrease TVS capacitance.

I thought of putting two TVS diodes in series to reduce capacitance.

What other ways can I reduce capacitance in TVS diode? 
Please give an example.

Comment: Can you share your circuit? And what's high speed? 100 Mb/s? Or 10 Gb/s?

Comment: Its 1Gbs ethernet line. For the circuit, it is simply a tvs diode that is connected between line to ground. Just that the capacitance of the tvs is around 1000pf  which is high.

Comment: What TVS diode did you try? I know they're available with capacitance down to 0.4 pF or lower, which gives ~500 ohms at 750 MHz (which is higher than you ought to need since GbE spreads the 1 Gbps over multiple lines and mutliple bits per baud)

Comment: The tvs diode I am using is a 5KP54CA. The capacitance is around 1000pF. The issue is the higher peak power, the higher the capacitance. The lower the capacitance, the lower the Peak Power. I need higher peak power because I want around tvs diode to handle about 60Amps.

Comment: May I please ask why you would like to reduce TVS capacitance?

Comment: Why do you expect 60 A on a signal line?

Comment: The current tvs diode I chose can support up to 60Amps, and it happens to be that higher power tvs has higher capacitance. In my case, the tvs diode has 1000pf. Higher capacitance will allow higher frequency to pass through. My ethernet line data support Gbps.

Comment: I am working on building a indirect lightning protection for Network Switch; therefore, I have chosen 60Amp as its max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to put fast diode in series. This diode has much lower capacitance than TVS diode. And when you have 2 capacitances in series the overall capacitance is dominated by the smaller one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVCh2V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I want to be sure about. The fast diode has different setting than the tvs diode. What do I need to look at to make sure that fast diode complements the tvs? If the amperage is high, wouldn't fast diode blow up or melt because it will not be able to handle the amperage unlike tvs diode.

Comment: @Kasap23 you have 2 options. You can buy packages that include this configuration (TVS+diode), or you can find a diode that is able to withstand transient you specify.